# Spanish permanent residency

Tags: schengen, spain, spanish-residents

I am non-EU citizen. I have a Spanish permanent residency (Residencua Larga Duracion) that expires in 2026. I moved to United Kingdom permanently a year ago for work purpose. I have the UK residency permit now.

With my Spanish PR card, I often go to Spain and border control doesn't say a word as I have the spainsh residency card.

I am wondering what would happen to my residency permit eventually in Spain ? Can I keep going to Spain and other Schengen countries with my spanish residency card until it expires in 2026 ?

Comment: If they notice that you have been permanently absent (short visits may not count) for 12 months, you may lose your long-term resident status. [Long-term residence or EU long-term residence recovery visa](https://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/londres/en/ServiciosConsulares/Paginas/Consular/Visado-de-recuperacion-de-la-residencia-de-larga-duracion.aspx): *... been absent from European Union territory for 12 consecutive months or ...*

Comment: Thanks, short term visits may not count. There is ambiguity there. 

What I have heard from professional immigration lawyers that the short visits do count and it should not be a problem. But there is no way to check if the card is still valid or extinguished

Comment: When you left Spain did you de-register ('Baja por residencia') at the padrón municipal?

Comment: I haven't done that. Is thats the way they find that I am no longer live in Spain ?

Comment: Short visits count as presence in the EU for the purpose of right of EU long-term residents following the ECJ decision this year. However, it only applies if your residence card was derived from the EU law and not Spanish national law alone.

Comment: This might be better on expats.

Comment: Yes, that would be one way for them to notice it. [Spain: register your residency - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/residency-requirements-in-spain#register-on-the-padrn). It is not yet clear if the new Entry/Exit System will include checks on the validity of residence permits on entry as proposed in the original 2016 concept.

Comment: So you continue filing and paying taxes in Spain?

Comment: Hi Geeky. The "Travel" site is for short term travel, like vacations. We have another site called [expatriates.se] for questions about living and working abroad. This question should soon be migrated there.